# How we can get cross sell products in cart graphQl

Tags: magento2

We are trying to fetch cross sell products for Cart GraphQL below is our cart query

```
    cart(cart_id: "WOmTvENRZPd6FxVIsAHkTC1WZ5fFwDrr") {
      items {
        id
        
        product {
          cross_tier_id
          name
          sku
          stock_status
          __typename
          small_image {
            url
          }
         
        }
        prices {
          price {
            value
          }
        }
        quantity
        
      
      }
    
      prices {
        grand_total {
          value
        }
        discounts {
          amount {
            value
          }
        }
        subtotal_excluding_tax {
          value
        }
        
      }
    
    
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me item list was coming empty. it seems that's why the data was empty or not working. I am sharing my fix it may help someone help --- Below is my modified cart query ---

```
    {
  cart(cart_id: "WOmTvENRZPd6FxVIsAHkTC1WZ5fFwDrr") {
    items {
      id
      product {
        cross_tier_id
        name
        sku
        stock_status
        __typename
        small_image {
          url
        }
      }
      prices {
        price {
          value
        }
      }
      quantity
    }
    prices {
      grand_total {
        value
      }
      discounts {
        amount {
          value
        }
      }
      subtotal_excluding_tax {
        value
      }
    }
    upsell_products {
      details {
        name
        sku
        small_image
        price
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**schema.graphqls** File

```
type Cart {
    upsell_products: cartInfo  @resolver (class: "\\VendorName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\Cart\\CrosssellProducts")
}

type cartInfo  {
    details: [itemsDetails]
}

type itemsDetails {
    name: String @doc(description: "holiday name")
    sku: String @doc(description: "holiday name")
    small_image: String @doc(description: "holiday name")
    price: Float @doc(description: "Get Product price")
}
```

Resolver file
VendorName/ModuleName/Model/Resolver/Cart/CrosssellProducts.php

```
   <?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace ImationSoft\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Cart;

use Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Cart\GetCartForUser;   
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

 use Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface;
 use Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface;
 use Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartManagementInterface;
 use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdToMaskedQuoteIdInterface;


/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
class CrosssellProducts implements ResolverInterface
{
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;
    
    private $cartManagement;
 
     private $guestCartManagement;
 
     private $quoteIdToMaskedId;
 
     private $userContext;
     public $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        UserContextInterface $userContext
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->userContext = $userContext;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {

        
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
        $cart_id=$cart->getQuote()->getId();
        
        $resource = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection'); 
        $connection  = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        $table=     $resource->getTableName('quote_item'); 
        $items = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM ' . $table .' WHERE quote_id = '.$cart_id);
        
        
        try {
        $upsellProduct = array();
        
        foreach($items as $item) {
            
         $productId = $item['product_id'];
$base_url = 'Store base url';
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
            // get upsell or cross sell products 
            $upsell = $product->getUpSellProducts();
            if (count($upsell)) {
                foreach ($upsell as $key=>$data) {
                    $upsellproductData = $this->productRepository->getById($data->getId());
                    $upsellProduct['details'][$data->getId()]['id'] = $upsellproductData->getId();
                    $upsellProduct['details'][$data->getId()]['name'] = $upsellproductData->getName();
                    $upsellProduct['details'][$data->getId()]['sku'] = $upsellproductData->getSku();
                    $upsellProduct['details'][$data->getId()]['price'] = $upsellproductData->getFinalPrice();
                    $upsellProduct['details'][$data->getId()]['small_image'] = $base_url.'/pub/media/catalog/product/'.$upsellproductData->getImage();
                }
            } 
        }
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            //show error message;
        }
                            
        

        return $upsellProduct;
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`product` node has `cross-sells` already, you can check the query here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/products.html#retrieve-related-products-up-sells-and-cross-sells

Comment: Thanks for answer but it is for product query I need for cart

Comment: it is the same, you really should try it out

Comment: how can you modify my query or let me know how can we merge it ?

Comment: The `product` node is already in your query, you just copy what you need from the document (the link) into your query.

Comment: Already tried it but not working thats why I was modifying it

Comment: Could you share your query?